# Modelling a time series with the "optimal" combination of N proxy series

Tags: r, time-series, cointegration

I have a time series *T*.

I also a universe *U* of time series  such that *A*, *B*, *C* ... *Q* are time series that belong to the universe *U*.

My problem decomposes into the following sub tasks:

1. Find a subset of *N* time series from universe *U*. Denote this subset *S*
2. Find an optimal scaling (a scalar matrix) to be applied to each of the time series selected in *S* such that:
   i. a new optimal time series *O* is created from the combination of the time series in *S*
   ii. *O* closely "tracks" *T* - i.e. *O* is highly cointegrated with *T*

I am thinking of implementing this in R. Can anyone please point me in the right direction of implementing tasks 1 and 2?

**Edit**

Note: *T* and the set of time series in *U* are all non-stationary.

Comment: What would be wrong with the regression of T on the series in S?

Comment: @F.Tusell: Forgot to mention, *T* and the set of time series in *U* are all non-stationary. I have updated my question accordingly.